# Puppeteer - Render PDF with unique page sizes per page?

Tags: javascript, pdf, puppeteer

I am currently working on a task to convert a webpage to a PDF.
The app I'm working on creates a PDF by opening a barebones webpage with '.page' div elements, then running Puppeteer to convert it to PDF.

Take this HTML for instance, where there are 4 pages with varying sizes:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="en">
> <body>
>     <div class="contents">
>         <div class="page" style="height: 436.656px; width: 950px; padding: 24px; border: 2px solid orange">
>             PAGE 1
>         </div>
>         <div class="page" style="height: 1450.344px; width: 1234px; padding: 24px; border: 2px solid green">
>             PAGE 2
>         </div>
>         <div class="page" style="height: 750px; width: 750px; padding: 24px; border: 2px solid lightblue">
>             PAGE 3
>         </div>
>         <div class="page" style="height: 3000px; width: 950px; padding: 24px; border: 2px solid red">
>             PAGE 4 (yes, this is a possible page dimension)
>         </div>
>     </div>
> </body> </html>
> ```

So now, I am trying to figure out if it's possible to render a PDF with unique page sizes based on the bounding boxes of these div blocks.

So for example, page 1 of the PDF is 437x950px, page 2 is 1451x1234px, etc.

**Is there a simple way to do this?**

The way I'm working on so far is one that's a sort of 'bruteforced' way of doing it.
Basically, rendering the PDF of the topmost page, deleting it, and repeating until all the pages are processed. Once that's done, merge all the PDFs into one.
It sort of works, but each page.pdf call *really* makes this slow. So I wonder if there's a more elegant solution to this.

> ```
>         var printPages = await page.$$('.page'),
>           pageBox;
>
>         // convert each page into a temporary pdf.
>         for (var i = 0; i < printPages.length; i++) {
>           pageBox = await printPages[i].boundingBox();
>
>           // create temporary PDF of this page
>           await page.pdf({
>             path: params.filePath + '_page' + i + '.pdf',
>             width: pageBox.width + 'px',
>             height: pageBox.height + 'px',
>             margin:0,
>             printBackground: true,
>             pageRanges: '1',
>           });
>
>           // delete the page div that was just processed.
>           await page.evaluate(() => {
>             var doc = document.querySelector('.page');
>             doc.remove();
>           });
>         }
>
>         // MERGE THE PDFS CREATED INTO A SINGLE PDF WITH ALL PAGES
> ```